# How to define the VPN PPTP port in OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, vpn, network

Is there any change to set the port to use when connecting to a PPTP VPN from a Mac?

I configured a VPN at home from Server 2008 so I can access my home server and use ports like RDP, VNC, IMAPS (Gmail), ..., that are blocked.

The problem is that port 1723 is also blocked. So I configured my home router to accept requests on port 443 (HTTPS) and forward it to port 1723 of the VPN Server.

Can I tell the OSX to use port 443 instead of 1723 for that VPN connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change OS X's built-in PPTP client's port. However, you can use a third-party client such as [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/). OpenVPN has many more options and will allow you to specify the port with which to connect to the server.

Good luck and happy tunneling!

Comment: OpenVPN does not have ANYTHING to do with the question.